# Posting string data into arrays from Rails views (forms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I've been trying to figure out how to post a string into an array from a user input text field that is part of a form. The `push` and `<<` methods work fine over the console, but I couldn't manage to save any string data into arrays from my forms. It always reports a type mismatch like this:

```
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String.
```

What is the appropriate way to deal with this ?

**EDIT** code example:

the array:

```
serialize(:name, Array)
```

Let's say that the form contains just a simple text field, nothing else. How would I store the input data into the array above ? Basically what's the correct format of this piece of code:

```
<%= form_tag(grids_path , method: "post") do %>
    <table id="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= text_field(:grid, :name) %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    </table>
    <%= submit_tag("Save") %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Where is your relevant code?

Comment: Sorry, edited. The code is basically non-existant as I simply need to learn of a way to usually do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to store a param into and array, you should do something like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'grid[name][]' %>
```

then the `params['grid']['name']` will contain an array of strings

Comment: I want to store it from my form which is in the view.

Comment: It's in the post now.

Comment: Rails is not reporting errors anymore, it just seems that the data isn't being saved properly. But that's another issue unrelated to this I suppose. This is what I'm looking for then, thanks !

Comment: By the way, a quick question. What if I used form_for tag like this:

`<%= form_for(@grid) do |f| %>` 

How would the syntax for the fields go then ?

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
<%= text_field_tag :my_string_a, 'String A' %>
<%= text_field_tag :my_string_b, 'String B' %>
```

In your controller:

```
my_array_of_strings = []
my_array_of_strings << params[:my_string_a]
my_array_of_strings << params[:my_string_b]

puts my_array_of_strings
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I'd like to store multiple strings into an array called :name, for example. The strings to be stored are from the form's text field.

Comment: Where in the controller should I put your code ? It reports this error:

`undefined local variable or method `params' `

Comment: In your example `<%= form_tag(grids_path , method: "post") do %>`, you used grids_path. Therefore, I am assuming the controller is `grids_controller`, and the method is `create`. Therefore you could add these lines above inside `def create`

Comment: You guessed right, I'll try your code out definitely just to test it all out. Thanks !

Comment: No prob! Good luck! :)